# How when I click the button, its contents push it up, not down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 buttons positioned: fixed in the lower right corner, when I click on the content that will appear and push the bottom button, this is not what I want, how to push it up?

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
let dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown, 0);

dropdownArray.forEach(function(el) {
  let button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
    menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
  let drop = el.querySelectorAll('dropdown');

  button.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!menu.hasClass('show')) {
      menu.classList.add('show');
      menu.classList.remove('hide');
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      menu.classList.remove('show');
      menu.classList.add('hide');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };
});

Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
  return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
};
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

[data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: unset;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.7rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.7rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: grey;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.7rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.7rem;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown-menu.hide {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-green btn-fast-access" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span>Click Me !!!</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-green btn-contact-now" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span>Click Me !!!</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please help me solve the problem or have a darker solution, maybe jquery

Answer (score 0):

Just move your "click me" code in html under it the drop down code like this!

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
let dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown, 0);

dropdownArray.forEach(function(el) {
  let button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
    menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
  let drop = el.querySelectorAll('dropdown');

  button.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!menu.hasClass('show')) {
      menu.classList.add('show');
      menu.classList.remove('hide');
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      menu.classList.remove('show');
      menu.classList.add('hide');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };
});

Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
  return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
};
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

[data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: unset;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.7rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.7rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: grey;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.7rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.7rem;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown-menu.hide {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
    </ul>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-green btn-fast-access" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span>Click Me !!!</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item6</a></li>
    </ul>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-green btn-contact-now" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span>Click Me !!!</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great! I am happy to have helped.